# comparing php varible which can contain a string or an integer

Tags: php, integer

I have a php variable $firstGrade which takes a strings like 'P6b', 'P7c' and if occasionally a negative integer -1 or -2. $firstGrade is the return result of running a function.

I need to know when the value is negative. I tried this:

```
if (    $firstGrade < 0  ) {
    echo ' we have a minus number for $firstGrade<br />';   
}
```

which seems to work - but it doesn't feel right - does it make sense to compare a string with an integer like this?

Comment: `if ( gettype($firstGrade) =="integer"  && $firstGrade < 0  ) {
    echo ' we have a minus number for $firstGrade<br />';   
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the type of variable and then do the comparison:-

```
<?php

$firstGrade = -2;
if ( gettype($firstGrade) =="integer"  && $firstGrade < 0  ) {
    echo ' we have a minus number for $firstGrade<br />';   
}

$firstGrade1 = '-23B';
if ( gettype($firstGrad1) =="integer"  && $firstGrade1 < 0  ) {
    echo ' we have a minus number for $firstGrade1<br />';   
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/710275